# Pack a box with beach stuff

Tags: packing

[image]

You have to place the objects so that no object touches any other or any purple.

This obviously needs a computer program:

[Packer](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/73109982/)

It can be done - it may be possible to do it more than one way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: why you hovering on me creep]

What can I say I am a sucker for scratch. though I had great difficulty with registering drags on most objects before I went into inspect code mode then it functioned great, the ball and plane were the only ones I could drag

Comment: i get that too, but the code works for me aswell. this isn't quite the answer i had, but seems to work, but everyone is cheating, so i'm not going to accept it for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is good enough:

[image]

Comment: Crappy question, crappy answer. Here, have a crappy comment.

Comment: Your picture is not a good reflection of your response, or the other way...